# capybara check if table column has some value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I am new to Cucumber and Capybara and I have a table where I need to check if a specific column has some value.

My step would be something like this: (in pseudocode)
I should see something with value: A,B,C

Then i need to query a table with a specific id and check if all the rows of the 2nd column have one the the values passed in the step.

In this example this should pass the test

```
some value | A
some value | B
some value | A
some value | A
some value | C
```

but this wont pass:

```
some value | A
some value | D
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Then /^I should see that all values in second column are either A, B or C$/ do
  all('#table_id tr > td:nth-child(2)').each do |td|
    %w{A B C}.should include td.text
  end
end
```

Parameterizing code (I mean A, B, C) is left as an exercise for the reader.